# inserting an object that has const fields into a container

Tags: c++, std, assignment-operator

Suppose I have:

```
class A {
public:
    const int x;
    A() : x(3) {}
}
```

And I'd like to create

```
std::vector<A>
```

g++ complains that the default assignment operator won't work since it tries to do `this->x = x`, which can't be done since `x` is const.
Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can't assign objects that have `const` member variables (same thing for reference member variables).

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `const` members were a good idea in the first place? Are you a recovering Java programmer by any chance? ;)

Comment: I deleted my answer (downvoted by people unable to read and see that "it's broken" in my post...), but to summarize it: it can be done, but the only way to do it is broken. Don't do it.

Comment: Please explain **what you are trying to do** rather than the broken way you think you might do it.

Answer (score 5):

> g++ complains that the default assignment operator won't work since it
>   tries to do this->x = x, which can't be done since x is const.

g++ complains correctly. Your class does not satisfy *copyable* requirement of the standard containers that is why you cannot use it with them.

> Is there any way around this?

Of course there is. Even more than one way.

E.g. the most obvious thing: you can remove `const` qualifiers from the members to make class copyable.

Or otherwise you can store pointers (or smart pointers) to the containers instead of the objects (one specific way to do that is what tpg2114 suggested).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like boost::ptr_vector? You would be storing a pointer to the object instead of the object, but that gets around the assignment problem.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the moral of the story is if you want your object to be copy assignable don't render it non-copy-assignable by having const or & members or a non-public copy assignment operator.

**Edit:**

For reference: With C++11 you can `emplace` into standard containers which is both more efficient and allows you to put noncopyable objects into standard containers.